# Calculating working time with overlapping events (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found similar queries on StackOverflow (e.g. [Finding simultaneous events in a database between times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044764/finding-simultaneous-events-in-a-database-between-times)) but nothing that matches exactly what I am after as far as I can tell so thought it OK to add as a new question.

I have a table that logs jobs (or "Activities"), with a start/end time for the job.  I need to calculate working time (you can disregard non-working days, break times etc. as I have that covered).  The complication is an individual can work on simultaneous jobs, overlapping at different points (the assumption is equal effort on simultaneous jobs), and the working time needs to reflect that. Minute accuracy is all that is required, not to the second.

Based on other suggestions I have this query, implemented as a table-valued function.  It will look at each minute that activity is running, and if any other activities are running in the same period for the same person, and make calculations based on that.  It works, but is very inefficient - taking over a minute to execute.  Any ideas how I can do this more efficiently?

Running SQL 2005.  I have done the obvious such as to add indexes on foreign keys by the way.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkActivity_WorkTimeCalculations] (@StartDate smalldatetime, @EndDate smalldatetime)
RETURNS @retActivity TABLE
(
ActivityID bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
WorkMins decimal NOT NULL
)

/********************************************************************
Summary:        Calculates the WORKING time on each activity running in a given date/time range
Remarks:        Takes into account staff working simultaneously on jobs
            (evenly distributes working time across simultaneous jobs)
Input Params:   @StartDate - the start of the period to calculate
            @EndDate - the end of the period to calculate
Output Params:  
Returns:        Recordset of activities and associated working time (minutes)
********************************************************************/

AS

BEGIN

-- any work activities still running use the overall end date as the activity's end date for the purpose of calculating
-- simulateneous jobs running

-- POPULATE A TEMP TABLE WITH EVERY MINUTE IN THE DATE RANGE
DECLARE @Minutes TABLE (MinuteDateTime smalldatetime NOT NULL)

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT @StartDate AS myDate
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(minute,1,myDate)
FROM cte
WHERE DATEADD(minute,1,myDate) <= @EndDate
)

INSERT INTO @Minutes (MinuteDateTime)
SELECT myDate FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

-- POPULATE A TEMP TABLE WITH WORKLOAD PER EMPLOYEE PER MINUTE
DECLARE @JobsRunningByStaff TABLE (StaffID smallint NOT NULL, MinuteDateTime smalldatetime NOT NULL, JobsRunning decimal NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @JobsRunningByStaff (StaffID, MinuteDateTime, JobsRunning)
SELECT  wka_StaffID, MinuteDateTime, COUNT(DISTINCT wka_ItemID) JobsRunning
FROM    dbo.WorkActivities
        INNER JOIN @Minutes ON (MinuteDateTime BETWEEN wka_StartTime AND DATEADD(minute,-1,ISNULL(wka_EndTime,@EndDate)))
GROUP BY wka_StaffID, MinuteDateTime

-- FINALLY MAKE THE CALCULATIONS FOR EACH ACTIVITY
INSERT INTO @retActivity
SELECT  wka_ActivityID, SUM(1/JobsRunning)WorkMins
FROM    dbo.WorkActivities
        INNER JOIN @JobsRunningByStaff ON (wka_StaffID = StaffID AND MinuteDateTime BETWEEN wka_StartTime AND DATEADD(minute,-1,ISNULL(wka_EndTime,@EndDate)))
GROUP BY wka_ActivityID

RETURN

END
```

Some example data (sorry for the poor formatting!)...

Source Data from WorkActivities table:

```
ACTIVITY ID | START TIME       | END TIME         | STAFF ID
1           | 03/03/2016 10:30 | 03/03/2016 10:50 | 1
2           | 03/03/2016 10:40 | 03/03/2016 11:00 | 1
```

And the desired results for a function call of `SELECT * FROM dbo.WorkActivity_WorkTimeCalculations ('03-Mar-2016 10:30','03-Mar-2016 11:30')`:

```
ACTIVITY ID | WORKMINS
1           | 25
2           | 15
```

So, the results take into account between 10:40 and 10:50 there are two jobs happening simultaneously, so calculates 5 mins working time on each over that period.

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: Have edited post to include sample data and results, thanks.

Comment: Sample data in the form of a table variable or a temp table are more useful: `declare @t table (ActivityID int identity(1,1), ....)` and then `insert into @t (.....) `. Thank you.

Comment: Sql Server profiler should help you. Are the JOIN columns are indexed? Can the calculations be avoided on JOINs? Filter dbo.WorkActivities rows into temp table should also improve the performance.

Comment: How did you arrive at 25 workmins for activity 1? or 15 for activity 2? Are you saying that if you have two jobs at the same time, in the overlapping area, each gets credited only 50% of the time? And if 3 jobs overlap, only 1/3 of the time? Then again, how did you arrive at 25 workmins for activity 1? I now understand activity 2, 5 minutes from 10:40-10:50, and 10 minutes from 10:50 to 11:00. But 25?

Comment: I don't know how large your dataset is, but I would lose the table variable and replace it with a temp table.  Table variables get no stats and always results in a table scan.  As teenboy mentioned, make sure your join fields are indexed and then rework them so the indexes can actually be utilized.  Set io stats on and capture the execution plan.  My guess is you are doing a ton of logical reads and full table scans.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding - caught up in other projects.  As suggested, indexing made a significant difference - creating an index with wka_StartTime and wka_EndTime sorted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by posters, indexing made a significant difference - creating an index with wka_StartTime and wka_EndTime sorted it.

(sorry, couldn't see how to mark the comments made by others as an answer!)